# Why does container already exist?

Tags: docker, go

I am trying to create a container via https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient?tab=doc as follows:

```
path, err := os.Getwd()
NoError(t, err, err)

source := fmt.Sprintf("%s/gogs/data-backup", path)
dest := fmt.Sprintf("%s/gogs/data", path)

defer os.RemoveAll(dest)

err = copy.Copy(source, dest)
NoError(t, err, err)

client, err := docker.NewClientFromEnv()
NoError(t, err, err)

ctx := context.Background()


gogs, err := client.CreateContainer(docker.CreateContainerOptions{
    Name: "gogs",
    Config: &docker.Config{
        Image: "gogs/gogs:0.11.91",
        ExposedPorts: map[docker.Port]struct{}{
            "3000/tcp": {}},
    },
    HostConfig: &docker.HostConfig{
        PublishAllPorts: true,
        AutoRemove:      true,
        Binds:           []string{dest, "/data"},
        PortBindings: map[docker.Port][]docker.PortBinding{
            "3000/tcp": {{HostIP: "0.0.0.0", HostPort: "8888"}}},
    },
    Context: ctx,
})

NoError(t, err, err)
defer client.StopContainer(gogs.ID, 5)
```

When I run, it complains:

```
=== RUN   TestGitAutoTag
    TestGitAutoTag: auto_tagger_test.go:55: 
            Error Trace:    auto_tagger_test.go:55
            Error:          Received unexpected error:
                            container already exists
            Test:           TestGitAutoTag
            Messages:       container already exists
--- FAIL: TestGitAutoTag (0.02s)
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
    panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x8 pc=0x9e1d06]
```

When I am looking at the running containers on my host:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                           NAMES
c2c9155514ee        drone/drone-runner-docker:1.2.1   "/bin/drone-runner-d…"   11 hours ago        Up 5 hours          0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp          drone-runner
6a7f43e6d541        drone/drone:1.6.5                 "/bin/drone-server"      11 hours ago        Up 5 hours          443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   drone
```

I can not see any container with name `gogs`. What I am trying to achieve is:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8888:3000 --name=gogs --mount type=bind,source=`pwd`/gogs/data,target=/data gogs/gogs
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your test code seems like it stops the container, but never deletes it.  Does `docker ps -a` (which also includes stopped containers) show it?

Comment: I've got `c05505dad155        gogs/gogs:0.11.91                 "/app/gogs/docker/st…"   42 seconds ago      Created                                             gogs
` The status is `Created` but not running why?

Comment: What do I have to do, to get the desired state?

Comment: "The status is Created but not running why?" Because you never [start the container](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient?tab=doc#Client.StartContainer).